# Clion Program execution error: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++, clion

Clion won't run any of my files. I have a basic file here:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error back and I don't know what is going on. This problem appeared out of nowhere.

The error:

```
12:35 AM    Build finished in 529 ms

12:35 AM    Error running 'untitled1': Cannot run program "C:\Users\shixi\CLionProjects\untitled1\cmake-build-debug\untitled1.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\shixi\CLionProjects\untitled1\cmake-build-debug"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Please help me figure out what the problem is.
[File Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z2Pg.png)

Comment: Check the project folder for the executable. It may have wound up somewhere unexpected. Also make sure any Antivirus you're using isn't panicking and destroying the file after it's built.

Comment: I posted a picture of my files. Please let me know if anything is missing.